# Connecting C++/WinRT class to Excel C# VSTO Add-In project

Tags: excel, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2019, vsto, c++-winrt

I build applications targeting Windows desktops. We have a large, in-house library developed in C++/WinRT utilized successfully for a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application. I have been tasked with connecting the same C++/WinRT runtime class to a Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) Add-In for Excel, so that we can deploy to both distributions simultaneously. There is known solutions for this with typical .NET projects: [Embedded C#/WinRT Support](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/blob/master/docs/embedded.md).

I have successfully ported the C++/WinRT component to .NET Core and .NET Framework applications following that example. I have not succeeded in supporting the VSTO Add-In. Currently, my VSTO project crashes with the following error at runtime when accessing the WinRT runtime class:

```
Error: System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not find Windows Runtime type 'WinRTComponent.Class'.'
```

With the following stack trace:

```
at ClassLibrary1.Class1.foo() in C:\Users\rtygood\source\repos\VSTO_Help\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs:line 16
at ExcelAddInTHING.ThisAddIn.OnSaveRequested(Workbook Wb, Boolean SaveAsUI, Boolean& Cancel) in C:\Users\rtygood\source\repos\VSTO_Help\TestExcelAddIn\ThisAddIn.cs:line 37
```

I have spent significant time attempting to get the VSTO Add-In to perform as expected. I believe that the barrier, causing the "Could not find Windows Runtime type" crash, is that the C++/WinRT runtime class is not properly registered through the project manifest (see "ClassLibrary1.dll.manifest" in linked project). However, VSTO automatically generates the manifest on any build event. And, from what I can tell, the manifest cannot be edited after build due to security checks by the VSTO installer.

I have performed every approach I know to get this VSTO project to utilize the C++/WinRT component. I am including a self-contained Visual Studio project that replicates my challenge, including a successful .Net Framework App (WinFormsApp.csproj), and the unsuccessful VSTO Add-In for Excel (TestExcelAddIn.csproj), each using to the same .NET DLL and C++/WinRT component:
[Reproducible Git Project](https://github.com/RobertTGood/VSTO_WinRT.git) (Note, after starting the Excel VSTO Add-In, save any excel workbook to perform the test).

- Q1) Is there any way to get the Microsoft VSTO Add-In project to utilize the C++/WinRT component without re-implementing the code as an interface in C#?
- Q2) If not, is there an alternative solution to make the connection, such as interfacing a .NET Framework app with VSTO that can leverage the C++/WinRT component?

Thank you for reading my question, and for those who provide their thoughts, opinions, or solutions.

Robert

Comment: I am just wondering, why do you need VSTO here, it does not seem anything in your scenario, but only troubles? Can't you expose your C++ directly to Excel as a COM add-in?

Comment: The overall library is stateful (used in hydraulic modeling and machine learning) and we want to expose tools that modify the state to a custom tab/ribbon, whereas functions and methods in the workbooks are read-only operations on the state. 

With the exception of one-way automation tools (i.e. C++ generates worksheets on-demand), I am not familiar with a COM add-in that exposes generic C++ APIs to Excel and back? If you have any recommended libraries or materials, I am more than happy to read them and experiment.

Comment: The installation does not have to be VSTO, however. I will accept any solution that allows me to reasonably re-use our C++/WinRT library.

Comment: The VSTO tools are designed to allow easy integration with office for .net platform, it is like a bridge between .net code and Excel. If you don't use .net platform there may be no point of bringing it in. You could create a (native, old-fashioned) Excel com addin. VSTO just wraps your code as one, basically. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/excel-com-add-ins-and-automation-add-ins-91f5ff06-0c9c-b98e-06e9-3657964eec72 the API of the Excel doesn't change of course, so the capabilities are the same as VSTO. Also removing .net in between could speed the things up.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Nikolay! We looked into developing an old-fashioned COM add-in, as you suggested. Our impression is that MS intends for "VSTO" projects to serve as the modern path for COM add-ins for office, and it was decided that we would be at risk of being phased out by commuting to an older release path. Whether that's true or not, I cannot say, but the state of documentation suggests it.

Comment: I did finally solve this challenge, however. We found that at the current time you cannot connect C++/WinRT to Excel VSTO until, in the future, MS allows users to modify the generated manifest. 

We did develop a near-equivalent solution by integrating SWIG into our build chain. http://www.swig.org/

We wrote a script that takes our same C++/WinRT API and converts it into SWIG's interface format, generating a very similar result as we saw with C++/WinRT. The performance seems to take a hit, but it works.

Comment: True, but even VSTO is sort of becoming deprecated now (in favor of the Javascript add-ins). Maybe you could try looking this direction? Anyway, I don't think they will be to drop the old-fashioned COM interface, no matter what)